# Log user actions in separate files by userId and date in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, logging

I need to separate my Logs of my Symfony2 project by user and day.

For example:

```
- 122-20150519.log (userId: 122, date: 2015-05-19)
```

I have now separate logs by day with the Monolog setup in config.yml like this:

```
my_log:
    type: rotating_file
    path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/my_log_%kernel.environment%.log"
    channels: [my_log]
```

But now I need to separate it by userId.

Do you know how can it be ?

Thanks ¡¡

Comment: Most likely you cannot - the path to a log file is compiled into a container and is a static string.

Comment: There is any way to create a new Logger Type and using it as a Monolog Logger ? Anyone knows the correct way to doing it ?

Comment: There is, try to make your own research first please.